# auto permissions on udev'd device files?

Tags: linux, configuration, mouse, udev, hal

This is a dupe from SuperUser.com . Folks over there weren't smart enough or willing to help me out; maybe it's more a programmer question than an administrator one:

---

I have an app that reads input from 4 (four) mice that are plugged in via USB in addition to the built-in touchpad. This is no problem for Ubuntu 9.10: hald notices the new devices and udev's them brand new entries called `/dev/input/mouse4` ... `mouse7`.

My app runs as a normal user app. The files in `/dev` belong to `root` and aren't readable to anyone else.

I don't have a problem doing `chmod a+r mouse?` once, but the devices come and go with every reboot and every time the dang rodents are plugged in or out.

Can someone please tell me a script or something to manipulate so my `chmod` happens automagically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information is easily discoverable, I just had to look at `/etc/udev/rules.d/91-permissions.rules` on a Debian configuration.  :-)

Some interesting examples pasted from there:

```
# default permissions for block devices
SUBSYSTEM=="block",                             GROUP="disk"
```

Looks like there's this "`GROUP`" thing to determine the group owner...

And, you can `chmod` stuff apparently:

```
KERNEL=="pty*",                 MODE="0666",    GROUP="tty"
```

Note the `MODE` part...

I'm sure RTFM-ing for the udev config file format will give you even more information.  :-)

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! I dabbled with udev a long time ago but wasn't sure udev was still the mechanism being used, as HAL seems to be all the rage now. And I wasn't sure how they relate. With Linux, once you know where to look the documentation is usually quite good but I needed some help with that first step.

Comment: my impression of HAL is that it's a bunch of annoying scripts wrapping the old stuff combined with misuse of Microsoft terminology like "HAL".  (y'know, 'cause Redmond has something called HAL, all of us should.)  but I can't say I've been following it.  :-)